# Doctrine - Remove of Entity with unidirection many-to-many relation fails

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have two entities. `Configuration` and `Role` with a unidirection many-to-many relation in `Configuration`:

```
/**
 * @var Role[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Role")
 */
private $roles;
```

Creation and update works as expected, but a

```
$this->entityManager->remove($configuration);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

wont work (foreign key violation), because Doctrine will not delete the relation-dataset

It only works with a manual removal of the relation AND an additional flush before the removal of the entity.

```
foreach ($issueTypeConfiguration->getRoles() as $role) {
    $issueTypeConfiguration->removeRole($role);
}
// It only works with this additional flush
$this->entityManager->flush();
$this->entityManager->remove($issueTypeConfiguration);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

I expect Doctrine to delete the related datasets

Answer (score 0):

Due to the manual creation of the many-to-many-table (Migration is not possible), I forgot to set the foreign key to `DELETE CASCADE`

I expected Doctrine to handle the deletion